# Unable to publish Jupyter Notebook from IBM Watson Studio to Github repository

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, publish, ibm-watson

I have been trying to publish my project Notebook created in IBM Watson Studio onto my GitHub account.

I have performed all the steps as per the instructions to

- created personal access token in GitHub and pasted it in integration tab in Watson Studio (Profile and Setting page)
- linked the GitHub repository path in setting tab of the selected Project
- selected the Notebook to be published and chose "Publish on GitHub" option

Each time getting the following message: -
"An error occurred while publishing the notebook
Try again later."

The problem is persisting for last two days.
Can someone please advise what is going wrong?
Or, any issue with GitHub?

Thanks

Comment: This does not seem like a question for StackOverflow community, but a question that should be addressed to Github or IBM customer support channels instead.

Comment: Thanks. I think I should do that.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

1. Create a 'master' child-branch in Github since the default branch is the 'main' one. The 'master' branch is intended to be the link between WatsonS and Github.
2. If you try to publish a notebook from WatsonS to github, a window will pop-up with the following bullets:

- Target pad.
- Commit message
- Cell content.

3. Scroll down this window and you will find relevant information about your notebook destination in github, which has the 'master' branch as default destination, hence it will turn into an error message if you don't have a 'master' branch in your github repository.

Hope you find this information useful.

Comment: Thanks. I used one master branch created earlier and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `master` branch to your created Repository for publishing the Notebook!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this on 9/16/2022. create a new branch and call it "master". Then go to the branch settings and click the arrows going left and right in the top right of the branch settings screen. Then make the "master branch" into your default branch. Then go to your IBM Watson Studio account - go to the manage settings - go to third-party integration - copy and paste this new "master branch URL into there.

This will allow you to publish to GitHub without the error message.

Comment: was facing same issue resovled with it.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `master` branch in GitHub and try again.

Answer (score 0):

just to add, any new branch created that's called `master` will work

Answer (score -1):

The Answer is Simple. You just have to change the Name from **main** to **master**.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAGIr.png)

This will treat Your Problem and will Connect your Watson to your GitHub.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).